# Where is deferred.resolveWith() defined in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, jquery-deferred

So, I'm looking into the jQuery source code, because I was trying to understand the meaning of "this" in a jQuery ajax success callback (which I found out works because of the deferred.resolveWith() method).

What I'm confused about, now, is that when looking through the code, I don't see an actual *definition* for the resolveWith() method that is called.

The source code is here, but I've done a simple text search to find all instances of the words "resolveWith" (listed below), which all appear to be calls to a method that simply doesn't exist:  https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.js

How does this work, in other words, where is the "resolveWith" method defined?

### Instances of "resolveWith"

```
function resolveFunc( i ) {
    return function( value ) {
        args[ i ] = arguments.length > 1 ? sliceDeferred.call( arguments, 0 ) : value;
        if ( !( --count  )) {
                deferred.resolveWith( deferred, args );
            }
        };
```

---

```
if ( !count ) {
            deferred.resolveWith( deferred, args );
        }
```

---

```
    } else if ( deferred !== firstParam ) {
        deferred.resolveWith( deferred, length ? [ firstParam ] : [] );
    }
```

---

```
function resolve() {
        if ( !( --count ) ) {
            defer.resolveWith( elements, [ elements ] );
        }
    }
```

---

```
// The ajax method's usage
if ( isSuccess ) {
    deferred.resolveWith( callbackContext, [ success, statusText, jqXHR ] );
} else {
    deferred.rejectWith( callbackContext, [ jqXHR, statusText, error ] );
}
```

Comment: Search for `"With"`, under "Add list-specific methods". jQuery is very... let's just say "weird".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's defined in [line  87 of `deferred.js`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/2.2.1/src/deferred.js#L87):

```
deferred[ tuple[ 0 ] + "With" ] = list.fireWith;
```

together with `rejectWith` and `notifyWith`. The `fireWith` function is a privileged method of a `Callbacks` instance (see [its docs here](http://api.jquery.com/callbacks.fireWith/)).

Genericity is nice, but you can overdo it :-)

Comment: Couldn't agree more on your sentiment, that was very confusing.  Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, the promise code in jQuery is very obtusely written.  I guess it's done this way in the interest of being compact, but it is very difficult to read or debug which does not make it great code in my book.